# NGINX core dump with trying to authenticate with LDAP

Tags: nginx, ldap

I am attempting to tie /.. locations to ldap configs, here is my config.

I have also included debug log with one "auth cycle"

I check under /etc/nginx/cores/ -- no dump files created..

Here is my configure option:

```
    nginx version: nginx/1.14.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --user=elkuser --group=elkuser --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-file-aio --with-http_realip_module --add-module=/opt/elk/test/nginx/nginx-auth-ldap-master --with-ipv6 --with-debug
```

config here:

```
user  elkuser elkuser;

worker_rlimit_core 10G;
working_directory /etc/nginx/cores/;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  debug;

events
{
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    ldap_server root
    {
        url ldap://maple.fg.org.com:3268/DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?;
        binddn "CN=user,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com";
        binddn_passwd "pass";
        require valid_user;
        max_down_retries 3;
        satisfy any;
    }

    ldap_server AEE0_WINDOWS_LDAP
    {
        url ldap://maple.fg.org.com:3268/DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?;
        binddn "CN=user,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com";
        binddn_passwd "pass";
        require valid_user;
        max_down_retries 3;
        satisfy any;
    }

    ldap_server DT00_MQ_LDAP
    {
        url ldap://maple.fg.org.com:3268/DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?;
        binddn "CN=user,OU=Services Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com";
        binddn_passwd "pass";
        require group 'CN=APP_SMY0_READ,OU=Universal Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com';
        group_attribute_is_dn on;
        require group;
        satisfy any;
    }

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server
    {
        listen       80;

        location /
        {
            auth_ldap "Enter AD credentials: ";
            auth_ldap_servers root;

            keepalive_timeout 300s;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        }

        location /logs/AEE0_WINDOWS
        {
            auth_ldap "Enter AD credentials: ";
            auth_ldap_servers AEE0_WINDOWS_LDAP;

            keepalive_timeout 300s;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        }

        location /logs/DT00_MQ
        {
            auth_ldap "Enter AD credentials: ";
            auth_ldap_servers DT00_MQ_LDAP;

            keepalive_timeout 300s;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html
        {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the debug log:

```
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: epoll: fd:7 ev:0001 d:00007F9ADA0FC010
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: posix_memalign: 000000000120D6A0:512 @16
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 accept: 10.94.204.71:55175 fd:3
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 event timer add: 3: 60000:604251266
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 reusable connection: 1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: timer delta: 215395
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: epoll timer: 60000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: epoll: fd:3 ev:0001 d:00007F9ADA0FC498
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http wait request handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 malloc: 000000000120D8B0:1024
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 recv: fd:3 1024 of 1024
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 reusable connection: 0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 posix_memalign: 000000000120C4F0:4096 @16
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http process request line
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http request line: "GET /logs/DT00_MQ/ HTTP/1.1"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http uri: "/logs/DT00_MQ/"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http args: ""
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http exten: ""
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 posix_memalign: 00000000011FDE90:4096 @16
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http process request header line
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Host: ulslogp15.fg.org.com"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Authorization: Basic MzE5NTMzMzAzOlJvYmVydHRoZWJydWNlMTMwNiE="
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http alloc large header buffer
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 malloc: 00000000011FEEA0:8192
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http large header alloc: 00000000011FEEA0 8192
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http large header copy: 541
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 recv: fd:3 214 of 7651
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header: "Cookie: WT_FPC=id=10.94.203.103-3121090448.30673262:lv=1536160575983:ss=1536160575983; _ga=GA1.2.1944342551.1536163722; __utma=235480898.1944342551.1536163722.1536164179.1536164179.1; __utmz=235480898.1536164179.1.1.utmcsr=org.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/cross-border/new-client/index.html; __zlcmid=oNhdj9cxtjakUX; _gid=GA1.2.739284147.1542741236; ga-intra-domain=MAPLE; ga-intra-directReports=No; ga-intra-hrPlatformDesc=Technology%20%26%20Operations; ga-intra-bufuguDesc=Global%20Tech%20Infrastructure; ga-intra-streetAddress=330%20Front%20St%20W; ga-intra-identityType=Employee; ga-intra-country=Canada; ga-intra-city=Toronto; dtPC=-; dtLatC=8; dtSa=-; dtCookie=DE7B89BC96D3D58755951932AC59C652|X2RlZmF1bHR8MXxVQ0cwK1NNKzl8MQ"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http header done
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 event timer del: 3: 604251266
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 generic phase: 0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 rewrite phase: 1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 test location: "/"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 test location: "logs/AEE0_WINDOWS"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 test location: "logs/DT00_MQ"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 using configuration "/logs/DT00_MQ"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http cl:-1 max:1048576
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 rewrite phase: 3
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 post rewrite phase: 4
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 generic phase: 5
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 generic phase: 6
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 generic phase: 7
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 access phase: 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Username is "319533303"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Authentication loop (phase=0, iteration=0)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 event timer add: 3: 10000:604201267
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: request_timeout=10000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Authentication loop (phase=1, iteration=0)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Wants a free connection to "DT00_MQ_LDAP"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Search filter is "(&(objectClass=*)(sAMAccountName=319533303))"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_write(len=94)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: send: fd:15 94 of 94
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: ldap_search_ext() -> msgid=2
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: timer delta: 1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: epoll timer: 10000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: epoll: fd:15 ev:0005 d:00007F9ADA0FC2C8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: http_auth_ldap: Read handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: fd:15 8 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=103)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: fd:15 103 of 103
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=100, msgid=2, msgtype=100
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: http_auth_ldap: Received a search entry
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug]

 1. List item

 109318#0: http_auth_ldap: Found entry with DN "CN=name\, name,OU=Business,OU=ORGNAME Brokerage,OU=Accounts,DC=dc,DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: fd:15 8 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=14)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: recv: fd:15 14 of 14
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=101, msgid=2, msgtype=101
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: http_auth_ldap: Received search result (0: Success [-])
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: http_auth_ldap: LDAP request to "DT00_MQ_LDAP" has finished
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Waking authentication request "GET /logs/DT00_MQ/ HTTP/1.1"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 access phase: 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Authentication loop (phase=1, iteration=1)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Authentication loop (phase=2, iteration=1)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: User DN is "CN=name\, name,OU=Business,OU=org Brokerage,OU=Accounts,DC=maple,DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Moving to group check
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Authentication loop (phase=3, iteration=0)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 Checking group
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 109318#0: *9 http_auth_ldap: Search user in group "CN=APP_SMY0_READ,OU=Universal Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=fg,DC=org,DC=com"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [notice] 57232#0: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 109318
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [alert] 57232#0: worker process 109318 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 57232#0: shmtx forced unlock
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 57232#0: wake up, sigio 0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 57232#0: reap children
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 57232#0: child: 0 109318 e:0 t:1 d:0 r:1 j:0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 57232#0: channel 3:8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [notice] 57232#0: start worker process 153645
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 57232#0: sigsuspend
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: add cleanup: 0000000001226B68
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: malloc: 0000000001216DC0:8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: notify eventfd: 11
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: eventfd: 12
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: testing the EPOLLRDHUP flag: success
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: malloc: 000000000120ACE0:6144
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: malloc: 00007F9ADA0FC010:237568
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: malloc: 0000000001228BB0:98304
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: malloc: 0000000001240BC0:98304
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll add event: fd:7 op:1 ev:00002001
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: add cleanup: 0000000001226CA8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connecting to LDAP server "10.238.112.191:3268".
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: stream socket 13
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll add connection: fd:13 ev:80002005
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: connect to 10.238.112.191:3268, fd:13 #10
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ngx_event_connect_peer() -> -2.
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer add: 13: 10000:604201292
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: connect_timeout=10000.
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: add cleanup: 0000000001226ED0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connecting to LDAP server "10.238.112.189:3268".
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: stream socket 14
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll add connection: fd:14 ev:80002005
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: connect to 10.238.112.189:3268, fd:14 #11
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ngx_event_connect_peer() -> -2.
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer add: 14: 10000:604201292
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: connect_timeout=10000.
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: add cleanup: 00000000012270F8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connecting to LDAP server "10.169.102.68:3268".
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: stream socket 15
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll add connection: fd:15 ev:80002005
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: connect to 10.169.102.68:3268, fd:15 #12
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ngx_event_connect_peer() -> -2.
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer add: 15: 10000:604201292
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: connect_timeout=10000.
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll add event: fd:8 op:1 ev:00002001
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: setproctitle: "nginx: worker process"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 10000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll: fd:7 ev:0001 d:00007F9ADA0FC010
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: posix_memalign: 0000000001219730:512 @16
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: *13 accept: 10.94.204.71:55176 fd:3
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: *13 event timer add: 3: 60000:604251294
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: *13 reusable connection: 1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: *13 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: timer delta: 2
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 9998
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll: fd:13 ev:0004 d:00007F9ADA0FC0F8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connect handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer del: 13: 604201292
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Initializing connection using URL "ldap://maple.fg.org.com:3268"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connection initialized
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_write(len=103)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: send: fd:13 103 of 103
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_sasl_bind() -> msgid=1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer add: 13: 5000:604196295
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: bind_timeout=5000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: timer delta: 1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 5000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll: fd:14 ev:0004 d:00007F9ADA0FC1E0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connect handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer del: 14: 604201292
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Initializing connection using URL "ldap://maple.fg.org.com:3268"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connection initialized
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_write(len=103)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: send: fd:14 103 of 103
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_sasl_bind() -> msgid=1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer add: 14: 5000:604196295
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: bind_timeout=5000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: timer delta: 0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 5000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll: fd:14 ev:0005 d:00007F9ADA0FC1E0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Read handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:14 8 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=14)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:14 14 of 14
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=97, msgid=1, msgtype=97
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer del: 14: 604196295
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Initial bind successful
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Marking the connection to "AEE0_WINDOWS_LDAP" as free
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:14 -1 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Dummy write handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: timer delta: 5
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 4995
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll: fd:13 ev:0005 d:00007F9ADA0FC0F8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Read handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:13 8 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=14)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:13 14 of 14
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=97, msgid=1, msgtype=97
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer del: 13: 604196295
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Initial bind successful
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Marking the connection to "root" as free
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:13 -1 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Dummy write handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: timer delta: 1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 9991
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll: fd:15 ev:0004 d:00007F9ADA0FC2C8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connect handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer del: 15: 604201292
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Initializing connection using URL "ldap://maple.fg.org.com:3268"
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Connection initialized
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_write(len=103)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: send: fd:15 103 of 103
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_sasl_bind() -> msgid=1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer add: 15: 5000:604196309
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: bind_timeout=5000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: timer delta: 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 5000
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll: fd:15 ev:0005 d:00007F9ADA0FC2C8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Read handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:15 8 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=14)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:15 14 of 14
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=97, msgid=1, msgtype=97
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: event timer del: 15: 604196309
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Initial bind successful
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Marking the connection to "DT00_MQ_LDAP" as free
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_ctrl(opt=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: ngx_http_auth_ldap_sb_read(len=8)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: eof:0, avail:1
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv: fd:15 -1 of 8
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: ldap_result() -> rc=0
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: http_auth_ldap: Dummy write handler
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: timer delta: 84
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: worker cycle
    2018/11/21 15:02:23 [debug] 153645#0: epoll timer: 59901
```

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: I am expecting nginx to search group for user, which it starts to do and the process crashes. Is this an nginx issue? I dont think I am doing anything wrong in the configs.